# Why aren't my stylesheets being included in the Webpack build?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

Webpack collected files (.css, .js) into a library and use it in another React project. The styles specified in the component do not pass, although the .css file is present and the styles are there.

UiButton.jsx file

```
import styles from './UiButton.module.css';

const UiButton = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <button className={styles.button}>Text</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default UiButton;
```

index.js file

```
import UiButton from './UiButton/UiButton';
import './index.css';

export { UiButton };
```

Webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
// const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    library: "uilibrarytest"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use:  [  'style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ 
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'index.css',
    }),
    // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    //     template: './public/index.html',
    // }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        "React": "react",
      }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
}
```

This is what webpack builds:

```
.button {
    background: red;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

How to make it so that when using a component from a given library, the styles are also pulled to it ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaders in Webpack are evaluated from right to left. In your configuration the evaluation order is 'css-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, and finally 'style-loader'. But 'style-loader' only injects styles into the DOM. You need MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader to be the first element in the "use" array. See below...

```
{ 
  test: /\.css$/, 
  use: [ MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader' ] 
}
```

Furthermore you can tell webpack to use MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader during production and at other times use 'style-loader'.

```
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production';
const stylesHandler = isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader';

...other config

{ 
  test: /\.css$/, 
  use: [ stylesHandler, 'css-loader' ] 
}
```

And in your package.json scripts,

```
"build": "webpack --mode=production --node-env=production"
```